# Connecting homomorphism in non-abelian cohomology

Tags: algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology, homogeneous-spaces, nonabelian-cohomology

Let $G$ be a simply connected, semisimple algebraic group over $\mathbb{R}$ and let $X$ be a homogeneous space for $G$ with finite commutative stabilizer $\mu$. There is a connecting homomorphism from non-abelian cohomology $\delta:X(\mathbb{R})\to\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R},\mu(\mathbb{C}))$ that identifies the image of $\delta$ with $\ker(\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R},\mu(\mathbb{C}))\to \mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R},G(\mathbb{C})))$, where $\ker$ means kernel as maps of pointed sets.

I wonder if it is always true that the image of $\delta$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R},\mu(\mathbb{C}))$? In the general setting of non-abelian cohomology this is false and the only general setting in which I know the result to be true is when the subgroup is taken to be central. Note that since $\delta$ factors via an injection via $\pi_0(X(\mathbb{R}))$ and since $\mathrm{H}^1(\mathbb{R},\mu(\mathbb{C}))$ is a $2$-group, it suffices to give a homogeneous space $X$ such that $\pi_0(X(\mathbb{R}))$ has cardinality different from a $2^m$-th power.

Thanks in advance to anyone answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\diag}{{\rm diag}}
\newcommand{\sH}{{\mathcal H}}
\newcommand{\R}{{\mathbb R}}
$No, the kernel $\ker \big[H^1(\R,\mu)\to H^1(\R,G)\big]$ does not have to be a subgroup of the abelian group $H^1(\R,\mu)$.

Indeed, let $G={\rm SU}(2,1)$, the special unitary group of the Hermitian form
$$\sH(z_1,z_2,z_3)=z_1\bar z_1+z_2\bar z_2-z_3\bar z_3$$
corresponding to the Hermitian matrix $\diag(1,1,-1)$.
Let $T\subset G$ denote the diagonal maximal torus, and set
$$\mu=T_2:=\{1,a,b,ab\}$$
where
\begin{align*}
1&=\diag(1,1,1),\\
a&=\diag(-1,1,-1),\\
b&=\diag(1,-1,-1), \\
ab&=\diag(-1,-1,1).
\end{align*}
Then
$$H^1(\R,\mu)=Z^1(\R,\mu)=\mu(\R)_2=\mu(\R)=\mu({\mathbb C})=\{1,a,b,ab\}.$$
We use the 1-cocycles $a,b,ab$ to twist the Hermitian form $\sH$.
We obtain the twisted Hermitian forms
\begin{align*}
_a\sH &=-z_1\bar z_1+z_2\bar z_2+z_3\bar z_3\,,\\
_b\sH &=z_1\bar z_1-z_2\bar z_2+z_3\bar z_3\,,\\
_{ab}\sH &= -z_1\bar z_1-z_2\bar z_2-z_3\bar z_3\,.
\end{align*}
We see that $_a\sH$ and $_b\sH$ are equivalent to $\sH$, whereas $_{ab}\sH$ is not.
Thus
$$\ker\big[H^1(\R,\mu)\to H^1(\R,G)\big]=\{1,a,b\},$$
which is not a subgroup of the group $H^1(\R,\mu)=\{1,a,b,ab\}$.

Comment: However, this kernel is a subgroup if $G$ is a *compact* simply connected semisimple $\mathbb R$-group.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the enlightening answer prof. Borovoi!